# Where can I find a visual traceroute utility for Window?

Tags: networking

I'm looking for a good, free, visual traceroute utility. Anyone know of any?

Comment: What are you after that tracert doesn't give?

Comment: @Ben: Maybe the "visual" part John mentioned in the title and question? :) A non-scientific poll of my office indicates most people associate "visual" with "gui".

Comment: @jscott: All I am saying is I honestly don't see the point of anything else - tracert gives all the info you might need, which was in fact my question...

Comment: @Ben: I know and I agree with you. Let's think like management for a moment... *ouch* ...Anyway, some people like to see pretty pictures rather than source data.

Comment: @Ben: Actually, I'm looking for a traceroute that maps the approximate geolocation of the router's to a world map.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tend to use [winmtr](http://winmtr.sourceforge.net/) for this.

Comment: That's the ticket.  I use that tool, along with "Java Net Perf" and "Performance Ping", all the time.

Comment: It is to bad that winmtr it is half broke under Vista/Win7.  I really used to like it.

Comment: I was having trouble with that link - http://sourceforge.net/projects/winmtr/ works for me

Answer (score 5):

I usually use a mixture of [winmtr](http://winmtr.sourceforge.net/) and [PingPlotter](http://www.pingplotter.com/freeware.html) depending on what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 4):

There is a new java-based project called Open Visual Trace Route. It's free at http://sourceforge.net/projects/openvisualtrace/ - It does include geolocation as part of it's free feature set. None of the other locally installed applications listed provide the geolocation to map view for free.

You can get it for free if you use an online tool like Visual Trace Route Tool at http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/visual-tracert/

Hope this helps, Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

[PingPlotter](http://www.pingplotter.com/freeware.html) and [VisualRoute](http://www.visualroute.com/lite.html) come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

You might try: [nmap](http://nmap.org)'s topology tab.